# IOS block not working, giving error:EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

Tags: xcode, class, objective-c-blocks

I've been having problems calling on a block, I keep getting the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2.

```
.h file
    @interface TheClass : UIView

    typedef void (^AnotherBlock)();
    @property (copy) AnotherBlock block;

    - (void) testMethod;

    @end

.m file
    #import "TheClass.h"

    @implementation TheClass

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self testMethod];
        }
       return self;
    }

    - (void) testMethod {
        self.block();
    }


    @end
```

And in the main view controller

```
.m file
    #import "MainViewController.h"
    #import "TheClass.h"

    @interface MainViewController ()

    @property TheClass *mClass;

    @end

    @implementation MainViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
        self.mClass = [[TheClass alloc] init];
        [self.mClass testMethod];

        self.mClass.block = ^ {
            NSLog(@"Remote Block Worked");
        };
    }
    @end
```

The button is linked up and working correctly, when touched I get the error message.
In the debugger there is a message that says:

```
    _block AnotherBlock <parent is NULL>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You should always test that a block pointer variable is not `nil` before calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `testMethod` before there's anything assigned to the `block` variable. Make sure there's something in it before calling `testMethod`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I moved the block creation to the viewDidLoadMethod, and just called testMethod when the button is touched.